# tomcat webapp deployment failing

Tags: tomcat

Error log when starting tomcat. I have wookie webapp in tomcat/webapps directory.

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory wookie
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

These are the three lines related to listener in web.xml

```
<listener>
            <listener-class>
                    org.apache.wookie.server.ContextListener
            </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
            <listener-class>
                    org.directwebremoting.servlet.EfficientShutdownServletContextAttributeListener
            </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
            <listener-class>
                    org.directwebremoting.servlet.EfficientShutdownServletContextListener
            </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Does it make sense to anyone of you?

I have more information

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.wookie.server.ContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not initiated or already closed
        at org.apache.wookie.beans.jpa.JPAPersistenceManager.close(JPAPersistenceManager.java:335)
        at org.apache.wookie.beans.util.PersistenceManagerFactory.closePersistenceManager(PersistenceManagerFactory.java:312)
        at org.apache.wookie.beans.util.PersistenceManagerFactory.initialize(PersistenceManagerFactory.java:256)
        at org.apache.wookie.server.ContextListener.contextInitialized(ContextListener.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4323)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4780)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:763)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:557)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1124)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1047)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1390)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:293)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:996)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:988)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:427)
```

Update::: SOLUTION
The above error was caused in my PC due to incorrect servletEngine.context.conf.dir path.
servletEngine.context.conf.dir=CATALINA_HOME/conf   (incorrect)
servletEngine.context.conf.dir=CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost   (correct)
/Catalina/localhost after conf is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done all the pre-requisite steps before deploying the webapp as per this list?

http://incubator.apache.org/wookie/downloading-and-installing-wookie.html#DownloadingandInstallingWookie-RunningWookiewithTomcatandMySQL

Comment: yes, several times over and with all different combinations eg. used both mysql / mysql5 for db.type.

Comment: servletEngine.context.conf.dir=CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost

..... /Catalina/localhost after conf is necessary. I do not understand why! conf.dir should need CATALINA_HOME/conf. What's catalina and purpose of localhost file in it. If I will need to run tomcat and apache on different servers, I think there will be many problems again. And why just one improper path created so very much of trouble is beyond me.
Anyway, thanks for your answer. you were right. mistake was totally on my side :-)

Comment: @vivek.m: Well, you fixed it yourself. You could edit your question to add this solution as an update - so it will be useful for future googlers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked disk space? I had a similar issue deploying a web-app and found that my /var partition was at 100% and gave these type of warnings.

Comment: thanks gdurham. I will keep that in mind for future problems. :)
This time source of problem was improper configuration of conf dir path